# Heroku error deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, webpack, bundle

I am trying to deploy, but this error can't let me go.

```
2017-07-21T02:57:41.976265+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
2017-07-21T02:57:43.657908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-07-21T02:57:43.658077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-07-21T02:57:43.988993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-07-21T02:57:44.004007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

This is my server config.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, 'localhost', err => {
  err && console.error(err);
  console.log(`Listening at 
  ${chalk.bold.cyan(`http://localhost:${PORT}/`)}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't specify `localhost`, or node will only listen on the local interface, and the Heroku process manager won't be able to see that your process is actually running.

```
app.listen(PORT, err => {
  err && console.error(err);
  console.log(`Listening at 
  ${chalk.bold.cyan(`http://localhost:${PORT}/`)}`);
});
```

Comment: You should mark that question as solved then :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer